# How to develop Google Analytics Reporting API v4 using GOlang

Tags: go, google-analytics-api

I'm developing APIs to get a report data of GA using **Golang** and **Google Analytics Reporting API v4**. However, even though there are libraries for Java, Python, and PHP, there is no library for **Golang**. Could you recommend me helpful reference or example? Or does anyone know library for Golang?

Comment: https://godoc.org/?q=google+analytics yields https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/analytics/v3 and others.

Answer (score 4):

I had authored an example repo for this some time back. Take a look - https://github.com/sudo-suhas/example-analyticsreporting

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can consider [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/libraries) as a reference, but for `v4` it's still in alpha